# QGIS Pie chart labels from column names

Tags: qgis, labeling, csv, chart

I am trying to get the proper labels for pie charts on my map. I want to use the column names of the table (.csv file) that is used for the pie chart as labels for the pie chart on the map. The column names show up in my layers pane as categories, but I am having trouble making them the labels of the pie chart.

How can this be done?

I have added the .csv file as a layer through "add delimited text layer" and have not saved it as a shapefile.

Map with pie charts and the layer pane showing the labels I would like to use:
[image: map]

Format of my attribute table:
[image: att table]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please describe more precisely, how you layer is symbolised, if you saved it as a shapefile or not, and add a screenshot of your chart-window.

Comment: @Erik I have provided some more information. Is it sufficient?

Comment: From a cartographic point of view your plan is at least worrysome. Because if every pie-segment is labeled like in the layer window, you will end up with way to many labels. Could you rather create a map with a legend? Besides, pie charts on a map are bad cartographic practice to begin with - but let's leave that aside.

Comment: @Erik Got it, thanks for the feedback! I will go back to the drawing table and find a different way to visualize things. If you have any suggestions as to how to incorporate a few key statistics, I would be pleased to know.

Comment: Maybe describe (in the commets or in chat) what data you have, what you want to visualize and if there are any restrictions (your boss needs to get it, or is it for a newspaper/flyer, etc).